# Very very simple, secure database for static site

Tags: database, web, static, content-management-system

I have static website with a handful of pages for a bit of self-advertising. I'm wanting to put a small database online to store some clients details, preferably with the same layout as my current pages. I've tried looking at some PHP scripts to provide a static interface to a SQLite database but I'm a bit unsure as to the security of the pages afterwards. I also looked at a Django app but I think it would take me too much time to get it up and going. Is anyone aware of a secure system or CMS that I could set up relatively quickly? Open-source would be preferable but not essential.

Many thanks.

Comment: What OS are you running, do you have root/Administrator access?  What is the general purpose of the site, (Blog, Straight Content, Downloads, etc.)?  Last is why SQLite, why not MySQL?  MySQL would probably be more secure.

Comment: @Nitroware: Why would MySQL be more secure? You can set the SQLite database's permissions to owner access only (chmod 600), just as you would to the PHP file that holds your MySQL credentials.

Comment: I've got Linux hosting with Webfaction. The site is for two purposes: details of some services I offer and as a login/frontend to a small database if that's possible. I looked at SQLite because I can't foresee needing to store more than about 2000 records and it seemed simple to link into PHP scripts, which in turn seemed simple to integrate into a page.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't actually need to be able to dynamically update the site (so that re-uploading changed files is alright), you could just bake dynamic content into static HTML pages with, say, a Python script (maybe even the [Sphinx documentation generator](http://sphinx.pocoo.org)?).

Answer (score 1):

Check out SQL Express [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/).  It's free, powerful, can be deployed quickly, and has great management tools and support documentation.

Comment: I'm guessing OP isn't using a Windows platform to host a handful of static pages, so MS SQL would be sort of out of the question...

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker is a decent solution that would probably suffice. It's made more for users than it is for developers -- that can be a plus or a minus, of course.

Personally, I think a PHP to MySQL solution can meet all of your objectives. If you don't have the skills for it yet, though, FileMaker or a solution like that might be a better fit.

Regarding your need to match the existing look and feel, a PHP/MySQL solution (or ASP/SQL, or ColdFusion/SQL, etc.) inherently achieves that because it uses your existing HTML and CSS.

There is more info on FileMaker and web publishing of databases at the following URL:
http://www.filemaker.com/products/filemaker-pro/web-publishing.html

Comment: Do I get downvoted for having a differing opinion? Is my answer actually wrong or does it just differ? This is a tough crowd.

Answer (score 1):

It would be super easy to do this with [ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/) but it is not free. You could create some CRM type functionality with Wordpress but you'd have to hack at the templates and defaults to remove all the blogish stuff. Perhaps SimpleCMS or ModX?